# Re-assignment in Pandas: Copy or view?

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],  
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                          'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : randn(8), 'D' : randn(8)})
```

shown below:

```
> df
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one  0.846192  0.478651
1  bar    one  2.352421  0.141416
2  foo    two -1.413699 -0.577435
3  bar  three  0.569572 -0.508984
4  foo    two -1.384092  0.659098
5  bar    two  0.845167 -0.381740
6  foo    one  3.355336 -0.791471
7  foo  three  0.303303  0.452966
```

And then I do the following:

```
df2 = df
df  = df[df['C']>0]
```

If you now look at `df` and `df2` you will see that `df2` holds the **original** data, whereas `df` was updated to only keep the values where `C` was greater than 0.

I thought Pandas wasn't supposed to make a copy in an assignment like `df2 = df` and that it would only make copies with either:

1. `df2 = df.copy(deep=True)`
2. `df2 = copy.deepcopy(df)`

What happened above then? Did `df2 = df` make a copy? I presume that the answer is **no**, so it must have been `df  = df[df['C']>0]` that made a copy, and I presume that, if I didn't have `df2=df` above, there would have been a copy **without any reference** to it floating in memory. Is that correct?

**Note**: I read through [Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and I wonder if the following:

> *Whenever an array of labels or a boolean vector are involved in the indexing operation, the result will be a copy.*

explains this behavior.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Thanks @acushner I went through that already, but could not find the answer to my question.

Comment: FYI, you will only get a view if its a single dtype (and even then its not guaranteed; depends on how you are slicing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that `df2` is making the copy, it's that the `df = df[df['C'] > 0]` is returning a copy.

Just print out the ids and you'll see:

```
print id(df)
df2 = df
print id(df2)
df = df[df['C'] > 0]
print id(df)
```

Comment: Thanks I updated the OP. I presume that garbage collection takes care of copies without references. Is that correct?

Comment: it sure will. i mean, it will get rid of the original, too, assuming there are no references to it.