# Getting SettingWithCopyWarning in case of column drop or modify for pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

From the sample dataset 'iris', i have created a dataframe df as follows :

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

From this i created another dataframe d2 & from the '_is_view' flag, i can see that the d2 is created as a copy (rather than a view). Since d2 is created as a copy, any operations on it (say dropping a column as shown in screenshot below) should not result in SettingWithCopyWarning. But still i am getting the warnings as shown below. Can anyone please let me know why i am seeing the warnings 1) in case of dropping a column 2) in case of modifying a column. If d2 was a view rather than copy, then these warnings are expected as it may result in modifying the df. But not sure why it is so in case of copy.
[image]

Comment: 1) If you plan to modify stuff, why not copy: `d2 = df[df.species=='setosa'].copy()`. 2) Don't use `inplace`: `d2 = df[df['species']=='setosa'].drop(range(6,49))`.

Comment: also a search for `_is_view`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101933/pandas-views-vs-copy-the-docs-says-nobody-knows.

Comment: @QuangHoang : Thanks for your reply. Yes, i can use copy to avoid the warning. But what i wanted to know is why the warning is issued even though its making a copy by default. Also you told not to use "inplace", can you please let me know what is the issue in using "inplace" ?